# Casting between classes with generics

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Can someone please explain why this code snippet is not working? Why is a not castable to b?
I was thinking about covariance and contravariance but as far as I'm concerted this is not applicable to abstract classes.

Compile Error:
Cannot convert type 'ConsoleApplication1.SVM' to 'ConsoleApplication1.VMSBase'   ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = new SVM();

        var b = (VMSBase<Model>)a;
    }
}

class SVM : VMSBase<SpecialModel>
{

}

class VMSBase<TS> : VMBase<TS> where TS : Model
{

}

class VMBase<T> where T : Model
{
}

class SpecialModel : Model
{

}

class Model
{

}
```

Comment: Though I can't be sure, because this topic gets confusing, I believe the solution is changing `VMSBase<TS>` to `VMSBase<out TS>`. If that doesn't work it would be the `in` modifier instead.

Comment: Here is the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx) on the `out` modifier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SVM` is a subtype of `VMSBase<SpecialModel>`, so it can be converted to one.

But there's no polymorphic relationship between `VMSBase<SpecialModel>` and `VMSBase<Model>`, because the generic type parameter `T` in `VMSBase<T>` is *invariant*.

---

In order for `VMSBase<X>` to be a subtype of `VMSBase<Y>` (where `X` is a subtype of `Y`), `T` has to be *covariant*. You mark it as covariant using the `out` keyword: `VMSBase<out T>`. This, however, forces you to use the type `T` **only** for return values from all members (methods, properties, etc) and **never** as an input value (method arguments).

There's another catch: c# only allows variance on interfaces. So you'll have to change both  VMBase and VMSBase to be interfaces.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SVM a = new SVM();
        var b = a as IVMSBase<Model>;
    }
}

class SVM : IVMSBase<SpecialModel> {}

interface IVMSBase<out TS> : IVMBase<TS> where TS : Model {}

interface IVMBase<out T> where T : Model {}
```

More info: [Covariance and Contravariance FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Bottom line is that `VMSBase<SpecialModel>` is not the same as `VMSBase<Model>`.

This is the same reason why this won't compile:

```
 List<ViewBase> list = new List<GridView>();
```

Although GridView inherits from ViewBase.

It's just how the language works, a limitation of generics you might say.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you could legally do the cast. Now imagine we have this method defined that eats models:

```
class VMSBase<TS> : VMBase<TS> where TS : Model
{
    public void GobbleUpModel(TS model)
    {

    }
}
```

Using this, we can now bypass type-safety in the following (surprising if you haven't seen it before) manner:

```
//SpecialModel2 is some other subclass of Model, not related to SpecialModel
SpecialModel2 incompatibleModel;

var a = new VMSBase<SpecialModel>();

var b = (VMSBase<Model>)a;

//forces a to gobble up a model that is incompatible with SpecialModel
b.GobbleUpModel(incompatibleModel);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why generics are not variant in C# is because it could cause typing problems: using your example, assume that VMSBase has a property of type T named MyProperty. If the casting was possible, you would be able to do something like:

```
var a = new VMSBase<SpecialModel>();
var b = (VMSBase<Model>) a;
b.MyProperty = new Model();
```

Now you just set the value of b.MyProperty to an instance of a Model; but that is not consistent with the type expected in VMSBase, which is actually SpecialModel.